# ¿Cuál es la función de src y dst en Docker-Linux?

Tags: linux, docker

Bueno estoy analizando este comando docker dentro de una interfaz de linux y me encuentro con el siguiente comando:

```
docker run -d --name mongodb --mount src=carpetadocker, dst=/data/db mongo
```

Bueno ya tenia creado la carpeta 'carpetadocker' en mi directorio, de hecho el comando si corre pero una vez que hago cambios dentro de mi contenedor creado 'mongodb' no se guardan los cambios ni ningun archivo en la carpeta 'carpetadocker'. Quiero saber si lo que hago esta bien o son otros los propósitos de los comandos 'src' y 'dst'.

Comment: `src` es la carpeta que quieres montar y `dst` es el 'mountpoint' en el contenedor

Comment: Bueno entonces no entiendo porque no me funciona... en cambio este otro si funciona: sudo docker run -d --name mongodb -v /home/ubuntu/carpetadocker:/data/db mongo

Comment: el el src debe ir solo el nombre de la carpeta o la ruta completa?

Comment: Creo que la sintáxis correcta es `--mount type=bind,source=/source,taget=/target`. [Documentación](https://docs.docker.com/storage/bind-mounts/#start-a-container-with-a-bind-mount)